# .get() method in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to know about `.get()` method in jquery. I just read the blog on http://api.jquery.com/get/ about the `.get()` method. I am using the same html but it is not giving the result as shown in document. Can anyone explain `.get()` in a practical way. What, when, and how to use it.

```
<ul>
  <li id="foo">foo</li>
  <li id="bar">bar</li>
</ul>

<script>
    $(function(){alert($("li").get())})
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.get()` method is used to return the native DOM elements in the collection. You can optionally pass an index to `get`, and it'll return only that element.

This is useful sometimes when you want to mix jQuery with the native DOM API. You might use jQuery to traverse the DOM, but then call `get` on it so that you can call the native functions on it.

[Here's **a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JnKCu/) demonstrating that, by using the native `scrollIntoView` method.

---

If you want to get a single element from the collection, you can also use regular array-like bracket notation:

```
 $('li')[0] === $('li').get(0);
```

---

**P.S.** Do not confuse this with the [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method, which will also return the element at the specified index, but wrapped in jQuery.

Comment: Also good to know that doing `$('li')[0]` would be the equivalent here of `.get(0)`

Comment: @Vega Yeah it's actually real nice for turning stuff into an Array real fast that way!

Comment: Thanks, can you give me demo of this

Comment: I think you fiddle has some problem, but i understood the .get method thank once again